# What is the flow of nhibernate Pure?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I want to know the flow of NHibernate pure c#.
What is the difference of castle active record and NHibernate pure?

Kindly teach me if there is someone who know well about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `pure` means without `Castle` or `Fluent`.

There is much to explain which cannot be covered in this answer so I will just note the steps.

- Create Entity (POCO) classes based on your database structure.
- Create mapping (.hbm.xml) files based on your Entity classes and database structure. To avoid mapping files, you can choose `Fluent` way which is other topic for discussion.
- Decide the location for configuration (web.config/app.config/code) and do the necessary configurations.
- Write CRUD methods in your `DAL` using various (`Linq`/`Query`/`Criteria`/`QueryOver`/`HQL`) ways available.
- Call `BuildSessionFactory` at startup of application.
- Call DAL methods.

NHibernate [documentation](http://nhibernate.info/doc/) is good source of information.

This [article1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nhibernate/index.htm) and [article2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21122/NHibernate-Made-Simple) should be good starting point for you.

For `Castle`, I suggest you ask separate question.

Comment: You don't need mapping files as of 3.x.  NHibernate itself contains mapping by code. http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/02/nhibernates-mapping-by-code-summary.html

Comment: I disagree that they are any simpler, but that's just my opinion.  The other thing about xml mapping files is that sessionfactory creation is slow when you use them.  mapping by code does everything in memory so that you aren't reading physical files and the startup times are much better.  This is especially the case when there are a large number of xml files.